# Increment a date by some time period

Tags: r

When using the "+" operator to increment a date (or date-time), how do i specify that the increment is in days (or months, or weeks, or years)?

```
> Sys.Date()
[1] "2013-08-23"
> Sys.Date() + 1
[1] "2013-08-24"
> ISOdate(2013,8,23)
[1] "2013-08-23 12:00:00 GMT"
> ISOdate(2013,8,23) + 1
[1] "2013-08-23 12:00:01 GMT"
```

Comment: You could create a function...1 week = 7 days and so on.

Comment: How could you extend that to months, having different numbers of days?

Comment: Yep, i gave a better answer.

Comment: @gcbenison Please refer to my answer below!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `lubridate::days`

```
> require(lubridate)
> Sys.Date()
[1] "2013-08-23"
> Sys.Date() + days(1)
[1] "2013-08-24"
> ISOdate(2013, 8, 23)
[1] "2013-08-23 12:00:00 GMT"
> ISOdate(2013, 8, 23) + days(1)
[1] "2013-08-24 12:00:00 GMT"
```

With lubridate, you can also use `years()`, `seconds()`, etc., or define your own `duration`.

Answer (score 6):

You could use *seq* for some basic calculations:

```
today = Sys.Date()
fiveWeeksAhead = tail(seq(today, by = 'week', length = 5), 1)
```

Or use a package like *lubridate* if you need more advanced functions.

Comment: Accepting the "lubridate" answer because it's the most succinct, but I definitely like the "seq" approach, because it's just core R.  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks. It's always better to avoid external dependencies, *unless* you *really need* it.

Comment: It's best to avoid external dependences, unless it _saves you time_.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `lubridate` to add days, weeks, months,... Here is an example of adding a month, and a week:

```
 library(lubridate)
 d <- as.Date('2004-01-01')
 month(d) <- month(d) + 1

#[1] "2004-02-01" 

 week(d) <- week(d) + 1

#[1] "2004-02-08"
```

Comment: Or you can do `d <- d + months(1)` to add a month and `d <- d + weeks(1)` to add a week with `lubridate`.